# Pop up for Low Quality comment options behind links

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

The popup for the 'leave a comment' is showing up behind the links at the top of the page:

All of the following screen shots are from a mac.

Original report in Safari:
[image: Original in safari]

Fresh install of Firefox:
[image: Firefox 26]

Current (31.0.1650.63) version of Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Current version of Safari:
[image: Safari]

I've been able to reproduce the safari issue on another mac.  However, the larger monitor (larger window, the delete dialog is further down on the page) means that I need to grab and pull the review pane window up so that the links at the top of the window.

Comment: I'm using Chrome... I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I can confirm this issue occurs on Chrome on Mavericks. This also appears to be a regression from a previous issue http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5422/close-dialog-display-bug

Comment: Going to see if I can get a dev to reproduce this, I can't (but that doesn't mean it's not happening)

Comment: @TimPost FWIW I just managed to reproduce this bug with FF 30.0 / Windoze 7. In this [dupe](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6723/31260) it was reported as reproduced with Chrome Canary / Windows, and [one of comments there](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/nav-buttons-floating-over-review-dialog-box?lq=1#comment18180_6723) even points possible cause: "checking the style it appears the `#delete-question-popup{z-index: 10 !important}` is not large enough to surpass the auto z-index of the buttons (and it overwrites the 200 of `.popup`)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be fixed in the next build. Keep an eye out for revision 2014.6.25.1680.

Comment: We know you're just after trying to get that 'status-completed' tag badge... (yea for fixes!)

Comment: @MichaelT trust me, it's better than Shog hunting for 'status-declined' badge at MSE :)